# Почему не выводится html в шаблоне WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал шаблон страницы в WP, но при переходе на страницу html код не отображается, хотя в source он есть.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Форма
*/
get_header();?>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <div class="modal__title">
                    Оставьте заявку и с Вами свяжется консультант Herbalife Nutrition! Консультант составит план питания и поможет приобрести продукцию.
                </div>
                <div class="modal__question">
                    <div class="modal__question--title">
                        У ВАС УЖЕ ЕСТЬ ПЕРСОНАЛЬНЫЙ КОНСУЛЬТАНТ HERBALIFE?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__question--button">
                        <div class="question__flex">
                            <label>
                              <input type="radio" class="option-input radio" name="yes" id="radio__yes"/>
                              <div class="question__text">Да</div>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                              <input type="radio" class="option-input radio" name="yes" id="radio__no" checked/>
                              <div class="question__text">Нет</div>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="question__hide">
                    Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с консультантом Herbalife, у которого Вы приобретали продукцию!
                </div>
                <form action="" class="modal__input" id="modal__input">
                    <div class="modal__input--item">
                        <div class="modal__input--title">
                            Имя
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal__input--enter">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                            <i class="manImg"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__input--item">
                        <div class="modal__input--title">
                            Телефон
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal__input--enter">
                            <input name="phone" required id="phoneMask" class="phoneMask">
                            <i class="phoneImage"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__input--item">
                        <div class="modal__input--title">
                            E-mail
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal__input--enter">
                            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" pattern="@">
                            <i class="mailImg"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__input--item">
                        <div class="modal__input--title">
                            Страна
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal__input--enter">
                            <select name="country" class="country__select" id="">
                                <option value="1">Россия</option>
                                <option value="2">Украина</option>
                                <option value="3">Грузия</option>
                                <option value="4">Армения</option>
                                <option value="5">Литва</option>
                                <option value="6">Латвия</option>
                                <option value="7">Монголия</option>
                                <option value="8">Казахстан</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__input--item">
                        <div class="modal__input--title">
                            Населенный пункт
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal__input--enter">
                            <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
                            <i class="cityImg"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__input--item">
                        <div class="modal__input--title">
                            Адрес
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal__input--enter">
                            <input type="text" name="addres" id="address">
                            <i class="addresImg"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__check">
                        <div class="modal__check--item">
                            <div class="modal__check--btn">
                                <div class="modal__wrap">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="s5"/>
                                    <label class="slider-v3" for="s5"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal__check--text">
                                Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">условиями передачи информации</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal__check--item">
                            <div class="modal__check--btn">
                                <div class="modal__wrap">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="s6"/>
                                    <label class="slider-v3" for="s6"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal__check--text">
                                Я хочу получать новости и анонсы от компании PPVSTAKANE
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__button">
                        <button disabled="true">Отправить</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Сложный вопрос. Может это потому, что твой код в модалке?

Comment: Если "не отображается" в первую очередь нужно смотреть стили и использовать инструменты разработчика в браузере.